# How to check if domain has SSL certificate or not?

Tags: php, ssl, https

Is is possible to get the details like if a domain (say `www.example.com`) is HTTPS ready?

I need to validate some URLs, whether they have SSL certificate or not. I know, by using `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` we can check our server details. but how can I achieve the same for other domains.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try to connect to `https://www.example.com` via any method, like curl.

Comment: @deceze I guessed so, but I doubt is that ok? I mean is that a correct way to detect?

Comment: There isn't really any other way. Either you can connect via SSL or you can't. The only way to know is to try it.

Comment: Be aware that some sites redirect from https to http.

Comment: @deceze, I posted an answer for my requirement. If you have time, please let me know if anything wrong in my post. Thanks :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Finally, I've ended up with the following my code:

```
$stream = stream_context_create (array("ssl" => array("capture_peer_cert" => true)));
$read = fopen("https://www.example.com", "rb", false, $stream);
$cont = stream_context_get_params($read);
$var = ($cont["options"]["ssl"]["peer_certificate"]);
$result = (!is_null($var)) ? true : false;
```

If HTTPS is enabled for a domain, `var_dump($var)` gives the **output** as shown:

```
resource(4) of type (OpenSSL X.509)
```

If it doesn't exist it returns `NULL`.

I've checked a few domains. It seems to be working fine. I hope it will help someone.

Comment: The danger with this approach is that you don't know if the certificate is valid or not. Many servers has SSL configured for some domains (ur using self signed certs) and it's common that these servers return the first available certificate if no domain match is made (to support clients without SNI support).

Answer (score 15):

This function will not only check if the domain has a SSL certificate, but also confirms, if the certificate matches the requested domain.

The most important part is the function [`openssl_x509_parse`](http://php.net/manual/function.openssl-x509-parse.php) which parses the certificate and returns all the details as array.

```
function has_ssl( $domain ) {
    $res = false;
    $stream = @stream_context_create( array( 'ssl' => array( 'capture_peer_cert' => true ) ) );
    $socket = @stream_socket_client( 'ssl://' . $domain . ':443', $errno, $errstr, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $stream );

    // If we got a ssl certificate we check here, if the certificate domain
    // matches the website domain.
    if ( $socket ) {
        $cont = stream_context_get_params( $socket );
        $cert_ressource = $cont['options']['ssl']['peer_certificate'];
        $cert = openssl_x509_parse( $cert_ressource );

        // Expected name has format "/CN=*.yourdomain.com"
        $namepart = explode( '=', $cert['name'] );

        // We want to correctly confirm the certificate even 
        // for subdomains like "www.yourdomain.com"
        if ( count( $namepart ) == 2 ) {
            $cert_domain = trim( $namepart[1], '*. ' );
            $check_domain = substr( $domain, -strlen( $cert_domain ) );
            $res = ($cert_domain == $check_domain);
        }
    }

    return $res;
}
```

Comment: Worked with some work around, for some reason $namepart always had 4 elements instead of 2.

Comment: It doesn't work if the certificate has multiple alternative names, for example try it on https://example.com/

Comment: I added this to make it work: `if(!$res && strpos($cert['extensions']['subjectAltName']??'',"DNS:$domain") !== false) {return true;}` (it doesn't handle the case where an altName is a wildcard)

Comment: Any way we can download the certificate and validate it towards a list of CA's?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a different solution that I found somewhere on github (cannot find the repo again...)

It's a similar approach to the accepted answer, but uses fsockopen to test, if we can establish a SSL connection on port 443. If the connection is refused then the domain does not have a ssl certificate.

```
function has_ssl( $domain ) {
    $ssl_check = @fsockopen( 'ssl://' . $domain, 443, $errno, $errstr, 30 );
    $res = !! $ssl_check;
    if ( $ssl_check ) { fclose( $ssl_check ); }
    return $res;
}

// Test it:
print_r( has_ssl('google.com') );
```

Comment: Why not just `function has_ssl( $domain ) {
    return @fsockopen( 'ssl://' . $domain, 443, $errno, $errstr, 30 );
}`?

Comment: Matt, you are right; the `fclose()` line is not part of the OP requirement as it does not contribute to the correct function response. But I think it's good practice also to close the remote socket again just to be sure it's all cleaned up :)

Comment: This answer shouldn't be used. The fact that a port is open doesn't mean that there's a website there and that the website has a valid HTTPS certificate.

Answer (score 1):

**There's no way to check if the certificate is secure or not using PHP alone without API (green padlock)**

But you can use this, which use a API: https://github.com/spatie/ssl-certificate